# @Output() EventEmitter does not emit when testing

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have following code

```js
it('should emit Sound on save', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'getBase64').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({
      then(onFulfill, onReject) { onFulfill('fulfilled!'); }
    }));
    spyOn(component, 'saveRecordedData').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(component.recorded, 'emit');
    component.isRecording = false;
    component.blobUrl = {data: 'somedata'};
    fixture.detectChanges();
    saveBtn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.fa-send')).triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.saveRecordedData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.getBase64).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(component.recorded.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Which tests following code

```js
  saveRecordedData() {
    this.getBase64(this.blob).then((s: string) => {
      const sound: Sound = {base64: s, mimeType: this.mimeType};
      this.recorded.emit(sound);
    });
  }
```

The problem is that in test I get error: **SoundRecorderComponent > should emit Sound on save**

**update: If I write expectations as following**

```js
 expect(component.saveRecordedData).toHaveBeenCalled();
 expect(component.getBase64).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
 component.recorded.emit({base64: 's', mimeType: 'a'});
 expect(component.recorded.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

the test passes :) : so I assume eventemitter works?

I believe `this.recorded.emit(sound);` is not called.

Why is `this.recorded.emit(sound);` not called?

**SOLVED**

This code worked

```js
it('should emit Sound on save', async () => {
    spyOn(component, 'getBase64').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({
      then(onFulfill, onReject) { onFulfill('fulfilled!'); }
    }));
    spyOn(component, 'saveRecordedData').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(component.recorded, 'emit');
    component.isRecording = false;
    component.blobUrl = {data: 'somedata'};
    fixture.detectChanges();
    saveBtn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.fa-send')).triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(res => {
      expect(component.saveRecordedData).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(component.getBase64).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(component.recorded.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

**note**: added `async` and `fixture.whenStable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can happen because promises bring asynchronity to your code and assertions are called earlier then promise.then callback. the easiest thing you can make is returned thennable obj, not a promise.

```
spyOn(component, 'getBase64').and.returnValue({
      then(onFulfill, onReject) { onFulfill('fulfilled!'); }
});
```

I removed `Promise.resolve` here